# PHP SoapClient - Multiple lines in attributes

Tags: php, soap, attributes, soap-client

I need help as I can't find SOAP attributes with multiple values and lines anywhere created by PHP.

I'm trying to reproduce this SOAP Request with PHP 5.3.x.
I'm having difficulty with the  part.

my php array $parameters works wonders except the attributes part:

```
$parameters = array(
                            'requests' => array(

                            'proposal_trans_request' =>  array (
                                        'TransType' => array( 'tc'=>'100'),
                                        'company' => array( 'tc'=>'500'),
                                        'product' => array( 'tc'=>'auto'),
                                        'inception' => array (
                                             'p_year' => '2012',
                                             'p_month' => '12',
                                             'p_day' => '20'
                                         ), // inception
                                        'p_number' => '0',

                                        'attributes' => array(

                                          'att' => $att



                                     ),//attributes
                                        'warnings' => array ()

                              ), //proposal_trans_request

                      ), //requests


                    ); //proposal_multitrans;
```

==============SOAP REQUEST============

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" >
  <soap:Header/>
  <soap:Body>
     <proposal_multitrans xmlns="***">
         <requests>
           <proposal_trans_request>
              <TransType tc="100"/>
              <company tc="500"/>
              <product tc="auto"/>
              <inception>
                 <p_year>2012</p_year>
                 <p_month>8</p_month>
                 <p_day>1</p_day>
              </inception>
              <p_number>0</p_number>
              <attributes>
        <att val="2" name="periodos" />
        <att val="2012-8-1" name="DateEna" />
        <att val="0" name="chkcabrio" />
        <att val="0" name="chksinag" />
        <att val="0" name="chkimmob" />
        <att val="00" name="xrisi" />
        <att val="" name="Anane" />
        <att val="0" name="Axia" />
        <att val="0" name="chkgarage" />
        <att val="1359" name="oximacc" />
        <att val="10" name="kritirio" />
        <att val="2011-01-01" name="Datekatas" />
        <att val="1" name="oxilyear" />
        <att val="0" name="Xozim" />
        <att val="" name="HlikiaodN" />
        <att val="2002-01-01" name="DateDipl" />
        <att val="" name="DateDiplP" />
        <att val="" name="DateDiplMP" />
        <att val="0,00" name="OmDisc" />
        <att val="F" name="Ekpidio" />
        <att val="1" name="radfilo" />
        <att val="1980-01-01" name="DateGen" />
        <att val="" name="DateGenP" />
        <att val="" name="DateGenMP" />
        <att val="0" name="chkmonaz" />
        <att val="0" name="chkdyoa" />
        <att val="09" name="Paketa" />
        <att val="01" name="NOMOS_I" />
        <att val="0" name="Metat" />
        <att val="0" name="chkpantrz" />
        <att val="" name="Eidikatim" />
        <att val="1" name="AstEf" />
        <att val="0" name="chkpiros" />
        <att val="0" name="Idzim" />
        <att val="0" name="chkkalerg" />
        <att val="0" name="chkthrafsi" />
        <att val="0" name="chkkairika" />
        <att val="1" name="chkodiboi" />
        <att val="1" name="chkodiatix" />
        <att val="0" name="chkodiboat" />
        <att val="0" name="chkanasfal" />
        <att val="0" name="chkatodid" />
        <att val="0" name="chkzones" />
        <att val="0" name="chkenoik" />
        <att val="0" name="chkolikiklo" />
        <att val="0" name="chkstuv" />
        <att val="0" name="chkmerikiklo" />
        <att val="0" name="chkaxant" />
        <att val="1" name="chkassist" />
        <att val="0" name="chkbomal" />
        <att val="0" name="chkolikat" />
        <att val="0" name="chkixos" />
        <att val="0" name="chkkakov" />
        <att val="997976100" name="IDNUM_I" />
        <att val="ΙΚΤ123" name="Arkikl" />
              </attributes>
<warnings>
</warnings>
           </proposal_trans_request>
        </requests>
     </proposal_multitrans>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Comment: What is  `$att` contains?

Comment: Is the above request what is required? Or was it generated?